# Which itemprop, itemscope and itemtype will be used for tenders in schema.org?

Tags: list, google-maps, email

I want to create schema.org for Tenders portal which provides information about Government and private tenders. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no specific item type for tendors so i beleive article type will best fit for that.

itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" 
itemprop="name" - for heading or title
itemprop="articleBody" -  for content.

You can use other itemtype as nested if there are person, business information in content of page.

Comment: I need start date and End Date as well, so would article be a right fit for this?

Comment: I think you could use http://schema.org/Event as nested itemtype to specify dates. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Offer which has the availabilityEnds property http://schema.org/Offer